# Line spacing in report

Tags: line-spacing

I need your help. I'm using this command:

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\normalsize
```

to create a spacing between the lines. But I'm still not sure where to insert it, wether before the `begin{document}` or after or before each text? Because there is one paragraph in the four pages I wrote till now, where there is no line spacing and I don't know why. Or do you know another command which would apply for the whole text? A package probably?

My code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=35mm,top=35mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry}
\titleformat{\section}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{8.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5cm}{2cm}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Kapitel1}

\section*{Einleitung}

\subsection*{1.1 Motivation}

\begin{large}
```

Comment: See the package `setspace`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel thank you Marco, I think you have to insert this: 
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
But it is still not working.

Comment: Please show us an mwe. I am sure that it works.

Comment: @abdu A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with `{}` on it). — Only inline markup (`\``) works in comments.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
\linespread{1.5cm}
```

before the

```
\begin{document}
```

line ? I think it should help.

Comment: hey, yes this one works too, however without the 'cm' so just \linespread{1.5}. But still having a problem with the last 3 lines I wrote. They don't have anyspacing, I don't know why.

Comment: Could you put some code in your post or a try to give an example ?

Comment: Yes sure,

\documentclass[10pt]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=35mm,top=35mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry} 
\titleformat{\section}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{8.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5cm}{2cm}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document} 
\chapter*{Kapitel 1} 
\section*{Einleitung} 
\subsection*{1.1 Motivation}  
\begin{large}

...

\subsection*{1.2 Ziel dieser Arbeit}

...

till now everything is Ok

Comment: Maybe add the code in your initial post so that users can easily copy it ?

Comment: How do I write the my code clearly in these grey shades? 

I think the linespacing disappears after I begin with  a new subsection.

Comment: @abdu edit the code into your question then highlight it and click the `{}` button in the web editor. (This just indents the lines by 4 spaces which is the wiki syntax for a preformatted code section) Please make it a _complete_ (small) document.

Comment: Ok! I fixed it! I was using `\noindent` everywhere in the text, that's why I had problems with the linespacing. But now I used `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` for the whole text and it's working =) Thank you all!